# Haskell in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, haskell

I am new to linux and have spent ages trying to get Haskell to work. I have given up on Eclipses module because for some reason it lagged incredible amounts. I have finally got GHCi working but can't find anywhere how I can save and load modules into the prelude. Like, I understand how to load them with :load "filename" but how do I make a .hs file??

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: `vi`, `emacs`, `nano`, `cat` with redirection, etc.

Comment: [`cat`? Real programmers programmers use butterflies!](https://xkcd.com/378/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're jumping a few steps ahead if you don't know source code is a text file and can be edited with your favorite editor. This might be a side effect of learning programming only with and within an IDE.

https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program

Comment: Great thanks, yes I have only used an IDE before which has made me realise just how clueless I am without them.